# Why is the peak efficiency of most charge pump less than boost converter,but still can be published in IEEE

Tags: boost, efficiency, charge-pump

I read some paper about boost converter recently ,and find some author will compare the peak efficiency of their boost converter with charge pump,and the  highest peak efficiency i saw is 33%,the other are 1% or even less 1%,on the other hand ,the peak efficiency for boost converter is 70%,or even higher than 70%,and as i know the peak efficiency is \$ \frac{real}{Theoretical}\$.

So i want to ask :

1. Why is the peak efficiency of  most charge pump low and  much less than the boost converter?
2. No offence,but if the most output voltage of charge pump is less than boost converter,and peak efficiency is very small,then what is its,charge pump, advantage?why can the charge pump ,which is small peak efficiency, be  published in IEEE?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that periodicals thing but there are situations with different demands, and if you don't need efficiency and the charge pump is cheaper, then you use it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH like IEEE

Comment: @PlasmaHH so you mean the peak efficiency for charge pump can be the same as the boost converter,or even bigger than boost converter?

Comment: no, I never said that, I said that the efficiency isn't always the primary reason to decide for one design or another. Also why would anything you said be a reason not to publish any papers? There is no rule to only publish things that are better than everything else.

Comment: @Shine Sun .Critical thinking means among other things that you do not believe everything that you read .It is totaly feasible to have boost convertors and charge pumps over 90% efficient.

Comment: Charge pumps can efficiently deliver 50 kV DC. I've made one that was 200 watts rated and it really, really scared me what it could deliver. It was for an X-ray tube. A boost converter won't deliver this sort of voltage.

Comment: Why shouldn't it be published? It is a technology in use (there are charge pumps integrated in many chips for generation of a programming voltage or in LCDs for driving the pixels, where you can't put a boost converter in) and if you can provide an advancement on that, you publish it.

Comment: @PlasmaHH Isn't the main purpose of charge pump to let the output voltage bigger than the input?If the peak efficiency is small,isn't it mean that the charge pump not good?

Comment: @Autistic Can you give me some reference?

Comment: @ShineSun: please read what I said. Not everyone drives a bugatti veyron because they don't need its speed. Similarily, not everyone needs the exact properties of a boost converter and a charge pump can be sufficient for your design.

Comment: Link to the paper and we might be able to tell you what's innovative about it rather than having to guess.

Answer (score 4):

Practical efficiency of charge pumps can be comparable to boost converters, often over 70%, sometimes much higher (over 90%). The theoretical efficiency is not 100% like those using an inductor, but that's of little importance in the real world.

Charge pumps are important, to give one reason, because they can be integrated onto an IC chip, whereas boost converters would require an external inductor with current technology. So EEPROM and flash chips that require high voltage can be self-contained.

Answer (score 3):

Advantages of charge pumps:

Can be very small.  No bulky inductor required.

Cheap.  Very few components required, and common jellybean components are usually good enough.

Can run unattended open-loop.  The output voltage is just a fixed multiple of the input voltage, minus some for any diode drops.  This is independent of clock frequency or duty cycle.

Because of point 3, can often be driven from some existing clock that is there for other reasons anyway.  The incremental cost of the oscillator is therefore 0.  In the simplest form, all you need to add are two diodes and two capacitors.

Unlike what you claim, efficiency can be reasonable.  However, charge pumps are often used in low-current applications where efficiency isn't all that important in the first place.

Comment: I wonder why everybody is thinking that low current applications don't require high efficiency - especially there you don't want to waste your precious milliamps... Bur maybe I'm misunderstanding you.

Comment: Because sometimes the alternatives are even less efficient.

Comment: @Arse: Because with low power, the total power wasted is still low, even if the efficiency is low.  When you've got circuitry drawing 100 mA at 5 V, it doesn't matter much to the overall power usage if making the 3 mA at 8 V to run a opamp is 20% efficient or 80% efficient.

Comment: @OlinLathrop so you are saying that it wouldn't matter that you need 120 mW instead of 30 mW of your 500 mW to get 24 mW of useful power? I guess that was a bit exaggerated. Maybe it's just the devices I have to work with, but at 36 mW input power I really care about efficiency gains - not because I care about the wasted power but because I care about the power I can put to useful work.

Comment: @Arsenal In most applications, that "putting the power I don't use to useful work" simply doesn't exist. If you're driving an EEPROM in programming mode with a boost converter, who cares about you saving 50% of power compared to the charge pump, if that only happens once every year for 12 seconds? Who cares whether your 40W backlight TV's pixel driver uses a cumulative 100 mA more? You're not dimensioning your TV power supply for *exactly* 100 mA, ever.

Comment: What if your car radio wastes 1W of power on inefficient conversion, if it's driving a 100W speaker array, and if the car's dynamo won't put measurably lesser load on the engine with that 1W less (arguably, such effects stack, but then again, if you need to accelerate a car that's now 10kg heavier because it contains more inductors for boost converters.. you get the picture).

Comment: @MarcusMüller Yeah I get that we are working on completely different systems. We can't use more power because the total supply power is limited to 36 mW of course if we can have all the functionality with 1 mW then the 35 mW can go to hell, but usually it's the other way round.